# Java string format in variable like Python

Tags: java, string

In Python, below code can be run:

```py
str = "i = %s"
print(str % i)
```

or

```py
str = "i = {}"
print(str.format(i))
```

I know that Java can format string using

```java
String str = String.format("i = %s", i);
```

But, I want to separate `"i = %s"` and `i` to make `"i = %s"` variable and use it on other codes, like below:

```java
String pathFormat = "/v2.0/%s/search";
System.out.println(String.format(pathFormat, userId);
```

Is it possible in Java?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: this is possible, please consider using string.format with only "%s"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that in Java just as in your last example.

```
String numberFormat = "i = %s";
int i = 17;
System.out.println(String.format(numberFormat, i));
```